# Take out certain sections of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, sections

My string follows the same character count pattern through each instance BUT some strings are longer or shorter so the solution would have to work for both long and short strings.

This is what I have:

XXXXXXX-​XXX-​XX|​XXXXXXX-​XXX-​XX|​XXXXXXX-​XXX-​XX|​XXXXXXX-​XXX-​XX|​XXXXXXX-​XXX-​XX|​XXXXXXX-​XXX-​XX

This is what I want to be left with:

XX|XX|XX|XX|XX

Where "XX" is the end of each section such as 0000000-000-XX

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know how to identify certain parts of this string to be removed. So no, I do not know where to begin. But yes, I have searched far and wide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically a combination of [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`join()`](http://php.net/join):

```
join('|', array_map(function($item) {
    return end((explode('-', $item)));
}, explode('|', $str)));
```

The inner `explode()` creates an array of all items between pipes from the given string, the `array_map()` takes the last piece of each dash delimited sub string and the final `join()` stitches them all together.

Comment: @joejnknsn The `$str` in my answer is where your string would go.

Comment: I get this error: "Only variables should be passed by reference" on your line 2.

Comment: @joejnknsn It's a strict notice actually. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize an output array to glue them together at the end.
First, would be to explode the string at point `|`.
Second, loop thru the exploded string (which is stored as array) then explode it again at point `-`.
Lastly, get the last element of the array.

like:

```
$output = array() ; //initial output

foreach(explode('|', $item) as $items){ //explodes the string @ |
    foreach(explode($items) as $itm){ //explodes the string @ -
        $output[] = end($itm); //appends the last element in the array of output
    }
}

$output = implode('|', $output); //sticks the output together with |
```

Comment: Thank you that is helpful in breaking the answer down. What if my output is a range of 6-14 but the results I have are as follows:

06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14

Is there a way to remove the first digit "0" if it is a single number?

6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14

Comment: @joejnknsn Yeah, `ltrim($string, '0')` would do that.

Comment: Great! Why does that "0" not apply to the "10"? Or rather, how does it know how big the left side is?